# Audio sample data from a Sound object

Tags: sound

When generating a Sound object by using Sound primitives, like:

```
Needs["Audio`"]
sound = Sound[ListWaveform[{{1, 1}, {1.496, .7}, {2.501, .3}}, 265, 1]];
```

how can I get the sample ("amplitude") data which is produced by the Sound primitive at a given sample rate?

Obviously one could export `sound` to a wav file and re-import it, but how to do it directly? Or let's say: what is the `Rasterize` function for Sounds, the inverse of `ListPlay`?

Sorry for this rather simple question, but I have been looking for some time and could not find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Your example evaluates to a `SampledSoundFunction[f , n , r ]`, which

> is a sound primitive that represents a sound whose amplitude sampled r times a second is generated by applying the function f to successive integers from 1 to n.

You could extract that function and see if it gives you what you're looking for:

```
Needs["Audio`"]
sound = Sound[ ListWaveform[{{1, 1}, {1.496, .7}, {2.501, .3}}, 265, 1] ];
sound
```

[image]

```
func = Cases[sound, _SampledSoundFunction, Infinity][[1]];

Print["rate = " <> ToString@(rate = func[[3]] )]
```

> rate = 8192

```
f = func[[1]]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, rate}]
```

[image]

```
NMaximize[f[x], x]
```

> {0.859436, {x -> 4.94378}}